# Share classes between .NET Framework and .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have some code on both ASP.NET Framework 4.6 and .NET Core 5. Around 7 classes are the same, and ideally they should not have their code duplicated, but simply refer to it.
The most appropriate place to actually host these classes is in the .NET Core 5 project.

I'm unable to simply reference the .NET Core 5 project inside ASP.NET Framework 4.6 and use the classes.
One solution I found is to create a Class Library project, but that would be one extra project in the solution just to host 7 classes.

Is there any other solution?
If not, then it means I can only duplicate the class definition, or create a dedicated Class Library project just to host these 7 classes?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a problem in +1 project

Comment: If your classes are commonly used by any other projects, they should be separated from a single project, the class library is designed to serve this purpose. Undoubtedly, create a new class library would be the most suitable way.

Comment: once a Class library is created one must choose the target Framework. If you choose .NET Core you won't be able to share it with the project targeted to Framework (e.x. 4.6.). How to overcome the issue?